# Why in this Gillespie algorith no oscilations in the simulation occur?

Tags: python, simulation

Here is the code that uses Gillespie stochastic algorithm. The attached image shows the overall reaction. The OFF means the off gene and ON means the genes that got *turned on*. Those genes should not use up and by my understanding they have to oscillate between ON & OFF states based on those constants given. Yet, the code spits me a graph where ON and OFF genes diminish exponentially and do not oscillate.

What have I done wrong?

[An image with the needed reaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9IkP.png)

[The result which looks smart but is actually stupid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGlO1.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
def zd4(Noff0,Non0,NmRNA0):
        
    # parameters
    k_on = 0.027 # min
    k_off = 0.167 # min
    k_tx = 0.25*60 # min
    k_d = 0.014 # min
    n_mRNA = 4 #number of mRNA units per one pulse
            
    steps = 120
    cycles = 50
        
    np.random.seed(2)
        
    T = np.zeros((cycles, steps+1))
    Noff = np.zeros((cycles, steps+1))
    Non = np.zeros((cycles, steps+1))
    NmRNA = np.zeros((cycles, steps+1))
    Nphi = np.zeros((cycles, steps+1))
    
    Noff[:,0] = Noff0
    Non[:,0] = Non0
    NmRNA[:,0] = NmRNA0
    Nphi[:,0] = 0
        
    for i in range(cycles):
        for j in range(steps):
            prod_ON = Noff[i,j]*k_on
            prod_OFF = Non[i,j]*k_off
            prod_mRNA = Non[i,j]*k_tx
            prod_PHI = NmRNA[i,j]*k_d
            R = prod_ON+prod_OFF+prod_mRNA+prod_PHI #whole reaction
            
        
            u1 = np.random.random()
            if R != 0:
                tau = 1/R * np.log(1/u1)
            T[i, j+1] = T[i,j] + tau
        
            R_list = [prod_ON, prod_OFF, prod_mRNA, prod_PHI]
            
            PR_list = [0]
            
            for q, R_i in enumerate(R_list):
                if R_i != 0:
                    PR_list.append(PR_list[q] + R_i/R)
                else:
                    PR_list.append(PR_list[q])
            
            u2 = np.random.random()
        
            if u2 <= PR_list[1]:
                Noff[i, j + 1] = Noff[i, j] - 1
                Non[i, j + 1] = Non[i, j] + 1
            elif u2 <= PR_list[2]:
                Non[i, j + 1] = Non[i, j] - 1
                Noff[i,j+1] = Noff[i,j] + 1
            elif u2 <= PR_list[3]:
                Non[i, j + 1] = Non[i, j]
                NmRNA[i, j + 1] = NmRNA[i, j] + n_mRNA
            elif u2 <= PR_list[4]:
                NmRNA[i, j + 1] = NmRNA[i,j] - 1
                Nphi[i, j + 1] = Nphi[i,j] + 1
                


    average = 100
    Tmax = 120

    Taverage = np.linspace(0, Tmax, average + 1)
    Noff_avg = np.zeros(average + 1)
    Non_avg = np.zeros(average + 1)
    NmRNA_avg = np.zeros(average + 1)
    Nphi_avg = np.zeros(average + 1)
         
    Noff_avg[0] = Noff0
    Non_avg[0] = Non0
    NmRNA_avg[0] = NmRNA0
    Nphi_avg[0] = 0

    
    for d in range(1, average + 1):
        tmax = Taverage[d]
        off_sum = 0
        on_sum = 0
        mRNA_sum = 0
        phi_sum = 0
        tcount = 0

        for j in range(cycles):
            for k in range(steps):
                if T[j, k] <= tmax and T[j, k + 1] > tmax:
                    tcount += 1
                    off_sum += Noff[j, k]
                    on_sum += Non[j, k]
                    mRNA_sum += NmRNA[j, k]
                    phi_sum += Nphi[j, k]

        if tcount == 0:
            Noff_avg[d] = Noff_avg[d - 1]
            Non_avg[d] = Non_avg[d - 1]
            NmRNA_avg[d] = NmRNA_avg[d - 1]
            Nphi_avg[d] = Nphi_avg[d - 1]
        else:
            Noff_avg[d] = off_sum / tcount
            Non_avg[d] = on_sum / tcount
            NmRNA_avg[d] = mRNA_sum / tcount
            Nphi_avg[d] = phi_sum / tcount

    ######_PLOTTING PART_############
            
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10))
    
    
    axs[0,0].plot(Taverage, Noff_avg, marker='', color='red', linewidth=1.9, alpha=0.9)
    axs[0,0].set_title('number of OFF genes')
    axs[0,0].set_ylim((0,Noff_avg.max()))
    axs[0,0].set_xlim((0,Tmax))
    axs[0,0].set_xlabel("t [min]")
    
    axs[0,1].plot(Taverage, Non_avg, marker='', color='red', linewidth=1.9, alpha=0.9)
    axs[0,1].set_title('number of ON genes')
    axs[0,1].set_ylim((0,Non_avg.max()))
    axs[0,1].set_xlim((0,Tmax))
    axs[0,1].set_xlabel("t [min]")
    
    axs[1,0].plot(Taverage, NmRNA_avg, marker='', color='red', linewidth=1.9, alpha=0.9)
    axs[1,0].set_title('number of mRNA units')
    axs[1,0].set_xlabel("t [m]")
    axs[1,0].set_ylim((0,NmRNA_avg.max()))
    axs[1,0].set_xlim((0,Tmax))
    
    axs[1,1].plot(Taverage, Nphi_avg, marker='', color='red', linewidth=1.9, alpha=0.9)
    axs[1,1].set_title('number of degraded mRNA units (Phi)')
    axs[1,1].set_xlabel("t [min]")
    axs[1,1].set_ylim((0,Nphi_avg.max()))
    axs[1,1].set_xlim((0,Tmax))
    
 
    
    for i in range(cycles):
        axs[0,0].plot(T[i,:], Noff[i,:], marker='', color='grey', linewidth=0.6, alpha=0.3)
        axs[0,1].plot(T[i,:], Non[i,:], marker='', color='grey', linewidth=0.6, alpha=0.3)
        axs[1,0].plot(T[i,:], NmRNA[i,:], marker='', color='grey', linewidth=0.6, alpha=0.3)
        axs[1,1].plot(T[i,:], Nphi[i,:], marker='', color='grey', linewidth=0.6, alpha=0.3)
    
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.grid()
    plt.title("Plot of average values")
    plt.plot(Taverage, Noff_avg, '-', label = 'Noff(t) - number of OFF genes')
    plt.plot(Taverage, Non_avg, '-', label = "Non(t) - number of ON genes")
    plt.plot(Taverage, NmRNA_avg, '-', label = "NmRNA(t) - number of mRNA units")
    plt.plot(Taverage, Nphi_avg, '-', label = "Nphi(t) - number of degraded mRNA units (Phi)")
    plt.xlabel("t [min]")
    plt.xlim(0,Tmax)
    plt.ylim(0,Noff0)
    plt.ylabel("average amount")
    plt.legend()
```

I tried changing initial values, but it's like the values somehow do not interact.